# Spring set parameter to AOP method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

all!
I cant solve problem with AOP Spring. I have a class

```
public class Minstrel {
public void singBefore(Knight knight) {
    System.out
            .println("Fa la la; Sir" + knight.getName() + " is so brave!");
}

public void singAfter(Knight knight) {
    System.out.println("Tee-hee-he; Sir" + knight.getName()
            + " did embark on a quest!");
}
}
```

Methods of this class will react to embarkOnQuest() method in Knight class. How to set Knight object as parameter to singBefore(Knight knight) and singAfter(Knight knight)? It must be in XML file? XML file:

```
<bean id="grail" class="au.adelaide.knight_example.grail.HolyGrail" />

<bean id="quest" class="au.adelaide.knight_example.quest.HolyGrailQuest">
    <property name="grail" ref="grail" />
</bean>

<bean id="knight" class="au.adelaide.knight_example.knight.RoundTableKnight">
    <constructor-arg value="Arthur" />
    <property name="quest" ref="quest" />
</bean>

<bean id="minstrel" class="au.adelaide.knight_example.minstrel.Minstrel" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
        <aop:pointcut id="questPointcut"
            expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" />
        <aop:before method="singBefore" pointcut-ref="questPointcut" arg-names="knight" />
        <aop:after-returning method="singAfter"
            pointcut-ref="questPointcut" arg-names="knight" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Stacktrace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorld' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: knight [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:454)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at au.adelaide.main.SpringInAction.main(SpringInAction.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: knight [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:890)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: knight [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: knight [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:208)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:194)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getMethodMatcher(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:169)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.buildSafePointcut(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:187)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor.<init>(AspectJPointcutAdvisor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 27 more
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Ah the knights... are you reading spring in action? :)

Comment: Yes, but this moment is not described as well as I want.

Comment: What happens when you execute your code? Do you get an Exception (if yes: please add the stacktrace)

Comment: Too localized......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
...
<bean id="minstrel" class="com.springinaction.chapter01.knight.Minstrel"/>
   <aop:config>
      <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
         <aop:pointcut id="questPointcut" expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..)) and target(bean)" />
         <aop:before method="singBefore" pointcut-ref="questPointcut" arg-names="bean" />
         <aop:after-returning method="singAfter" pointcut-ref="questPointcut" arg-names="bean" />
      </aop:aspect>
   </aop:config>
...
```

This is similar to -

```
public class KnightOfTheRoundTable implements Knight {
   …
   private Minstrel minstrel;
   public void setMinstrel(Minstrel minstrel) {
      this.minstrel = minstrel;
   } 
   …
   public HolyGrail embarkOnQuest() throws QuestFailedException {
      minstrel.singBefore(this);
      HolyGrail grail = quest.embark();       
      minstrel.singAfter(this);

      return grail;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<aop:pointcut id="questPointcut"
            expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..)) and this(knight)" />
```

That use the `this` poincut designator in the parameter binding form.

see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-names